# What wire-to-board connector is this?

Tags: connector

I thought this would be trivial to source. Looks like the usual molex style connector. But it seems to have a 1.8 mm pitch:

[image: wire-to-board connector with 1.8mm pitch]

Any ideas what kind of connector this is? I cannot find anything with this pitch. I'd rather not cut the cables for this project.

Comment: It's 2mm pitch- 9 spaces take 18mm. Don't look at just a single space if you want accuracy.

Comment: I didn't. I'm just too stupid to count spaces instead of leads...

Comment: Happens to just about everyone- see [off-by-one error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) and in particular the [fencepost error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope I had my names wrong, looks like a JST http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/search_e.php?type=1&id=1&page=1

Comment: Unfourtunately, none of the JST ones has 1.8mm pitch (except some with only two terminals).

Comment: try these http://www.molex.com/molex/products/group?key=wire_to_board_connectors&channel=PRODUCTS

Comment: actually don't see 1.8mm there either, are you sure it's not 1.7 or 2?

Comment: Actually from the photo it's a 2 mm pitch...

Comment: DOH! you are right! It is 2mm. Ohhh this is so embarrassing. 10 positions clearly covering 18mm. That's not 18/10 since there are only nine gaps. If my math prof ever hears of this... I haven't quite identified the exact type, but 2mm is very common. I just dig through digikey images.

Comment: It is a JST PH connector. http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=199.